# Catel Extensions EntityFramework5

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, catel

I'm using the Catel Extensions EntityFramework5 for repository and unit of work pattern.
I'm trying to implement repository for a derived class DailyMacroValue where DailyMacroValue :DailyPrice

there is the code:

```
public class DailyMacroValueRepository :EntityRepositoryBase<DailyMacroValue, int>, IDailyMacroValueRepository
    {
        private XXXEntities _dbContext;
        public DailyMacroValueRepository(DbContext dbContext)
            : base(dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext as XXXEntities;
        }

    }
    public interface IDailyMacroValueRepository : IEntityRepository<DailyMacroValue, int>
    {

    }
}
```

once I'm trying to get the repository I'm getting the excelption:

at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Catel.Data.DbContextExtensions.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_3() in c:\Source\Catel\src\Catel.Extensions.EntityFramework5\Catel.Extensions.EntityFramework5.NET40\Extensions\DbContextExtensions.cs:line 116

I'm sure this is not the correct way of implementation, does anyone have a reference of inheritance implementation ?

more info:
**Message**
Sequence contains no matching element
**stack trace**

at Catel.IoC.TypeFactory.TryCreateWithConstructorInjectionWithParameters(Type typeToConstruct, ConstructorInfo constructorInfo, Object[] parameters) in c:\Source\Catel\src\Catel.Core\Catel.Core.NET40\IoC\TypeFactory.cs:line 402
   at Catel.IoC.TypeFactory.CreateInstanceWithParameters(Type typeToConstruct, Object[] parameters) in c:\Source\Catel\src\Catel.Core\Catel.Core.NET40\IoC\TypeFactory.cs:line 243
   at Catel.Data.UnitOfWork.GetRepositoryTEntityRepository in c:\Source\Catel\src\Catel.Extensions.EntityFramework5\Catel.Extensions.EntityFramework5.NET40\Data\UnitOfWork.cs:line 186
   at DDServices.DALQuateService.GetQuatesForSingelByDates(Int32 companyEquetyID, DateTime dtFrom, DateTime dtTo) in c:\Dev\ASIF\DDServices\DALQuateService.cs:line 242
   at DDServices.DALQuateService.ConcatPreviouseDateForSplit(CompanyEquityDailyPrice item) in c:\Dev\ASIF\DDServices\DALQuateService.cs:line 160
   at DDServices.DALQuateService.SaveCompanyEquitiesHistoricalDailyPricesData(List`1 dailyPrices, Boolean forceBackUpdate) in c:\Dev\ASIF\DDServices\DALQuateService.cs:line 83

10x, 
rony

Comment: Can you post the whole exception including the inner exception? It looks good. No need to store the dBContext yourself btw.

Comment: Thanks Greet, Sorry to late replay ..

Comment: I've added the stack trace and the exception message to the body of the question.

Comment: can u please refer to a sample with inheritance ?

Comment: We don't have examples with inheritance, nor do we officially support it. Sequence contains no matching element looks like your are using First instead of FirstOrDefault.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have examples with inheritance, nor do we officially support it. Sequence contains no matching element looks like your are using First instead of FirstOrDefault.